# Uneven surface under drywall

Tags: drywall

I have this small 2 inch concrete footing under my bottom plate that I am going to drywall over shortly. The concrete protrudes past the plate a half inch in some places, making it very uneven at the bottom. Should I just screw the sheetrock to the bottom plate, nearly 2 inches off the floor, then use large molding? Or is there a better way to do this? [image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah just go with the moulding idea. Image a room with 8'3" ceilings. The drywallers aren't going to cut a 2.5" strip, they just leave the gap at the bottom.